# POSTGRESQL: Sum a field when 2 condtions are met

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, field

I wonder if i could get some help with this.

I have a query im trying to write in the query i use 3 fields: ID, Option and amount.

I need to group my unique ID's then in that Group i need to split up by option white totaling the amounts per option.

eg: 
ID: 11111 
--> OptionA 500
--> OptionB 100

---

ID: 11112
--> OptionA 150
--> OptionB 100
etc....

Hope i was discriptive enough :)

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Could you publish your db structure and example of data & example of result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for a conditional sum like in the below example:

```
SELECT id,
       Sum( CASE WHEN OptionA = 500 THEN aumount END ) As Sum_ForOptionA500,
       Sum( CASE WHEN OptionB = 100 THEN aumount END ) As Sum_ForOptionB100,
       Sum( CASE WHEN OptionA = 200 AND OptionB = 300 THEN aumount END )
                     As Sum_ForOptionA200_B300,
       .......
FROM table
GROUP BY id
```

---

Or just calculate sums for all available combination of options, like

```
SELECT id, optionA, optionB, sum( Amount )
FROM table
GROUP BY id, optionA, optionB
```